# Need to add xsi to the namespace

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I have this as input

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
  <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId></MsgId>
      <CreDtTm></CreDtTm>
      <InitgPty>
        <Id>
          <OrgId>
            <BICOrBEI></BICOrBEI>
          </OrgId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
      <OrgnlMsgId></OrgnlMsgId>
      <OrgnlMsgNmId></OrgnlMsgNmId>
      <OrgnlNbOfTxs></OrgnlNbOfTxs>
      <OrgnlCtrlSum></OrgnlCtrlSum>
      <GrpSts></GrpSts>
    </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
  </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

I need below as my out put with having details of the xsi as well

```
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
<CstmrPmtStsRpt>
        <GrpHdr>
          <MsgId></MsgId>
          <CreDtTm></CreDtTm>
          <InitgPty>
            <Id>
              <OrgId>
                <BICOrBEI></BICOrBEI>
              </OrgId>
            </Id>
          </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
        <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
          <OrgnlMsgId></OrgnlMsgId>
          <OrgnlMsgNmId></OrgnlMsgNmId>
          <OrgnlNbOfTxs></OrgnlNbOfTxs>
          <OrgnlCtrlSum></OrgnlCtrlSum>
          <GrpSts></GrpSts>
        </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
      </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
    </Document>
```

> I am currently using xslt as which i am trying to use for putting
>   namespace and xsi, but as i cannot use this on my receive port due to
>   the fact i need to use pass through pipeline

```
*<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Document">
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
        </Document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

*

Need assistance on the same

Comment: I am awaiting some response and help here

Answer (score 2):

Your matcher `<xsl:template match="/Document">` is never called, because it lacks the namespace.

Add the namespace to your XSL with whatever alias name and add the alias to your matcher.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:iso="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
...
<xsl:template match="/iso:Document">
```

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:iso="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
    <xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/iso:Document">
        <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
        </Document>
    Its working

But now I am not able to get the xsi bits to my namespace

Comment: How do you mean Document is working, but XSI namespace not. The namespace is added as part of the Document element.

Comment: Hi Burki , I need namespace and xsi both added to the Document elsement.In this case namespace is there but missing the xsi. I need as <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: This is exactly how the Document element looks for me after the transformation (I use Saxon HE). Are you sure the document matcher works now? It would help if you update your question with the most current input xml, xsl stylesheet, result and what is not achieved in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Used a Disassembler in a custom pipeline and it worked.